# Can I ignore the global .gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore

My global .gitignore is generally great but for this one off project I don't want the global rules applied.

How can I remove the global .gitignore rules for this one freak repository?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Run this command in your repo:

```
git config --local core.excludesfile false
```

Comment: $git add [file] -f helped move a few tricky files along too. Thanks