# gitignore - include everything in repo directory, ignore nothing, completely discard any user/machine ignores

Tags: git

I have a repo.  I want everything in the repo's directory to be included.  I want to make it so that any user or machine settings related to ignoring files are not used at all.  Anyone who pulls this repo will have to check-in any file in any directory within the repo.

An empty .gitignore doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do what you are proposing.  The control of all that stuff is left to the user.  It is almost impossible to force a user to do something you want them to do, if they don't want to do it.

Comment: @TrippKinetics - I should note that my motivation here isn't control over other users' actions, I was using other users to more fully explain the question.  In reality, I'm tired of messing with gitignore for myself.  The tooling around this is horrible.  I'm spending way too much time trying to figure out why a particular file is being ignored and I have a repo that I truly want everything included in.

Comment: This is something I run into frequently; many people on the team have a global .gitignore that is valid for all but a single repository.

We keep licensed DLL's that we've put into our private NuGet gallery in their own repo as backup.

It would be nice on that single repo to have an ignore override, otherwise I'm the only one who can add to it OR people have to take off their global ignore then add it back which isn't really a good experience...

Comment: It doesn't matter if the other user is you or not.  It is still very difficult.

Comment: This seems to work:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728053/can-i-ignore-the-global-gitignore